# Using a UIPickerView instead of UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm sure somewhere here is the solution, but I've searched for that for a long time now but did not find anything

So my setup:
.h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *valueOne;
IBOutlet UITextField *valueTwo;
    IBOutlet UILabel *total; 


- (IBAction)Lange;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *valueOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *valueTwo;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)Lange{
    float f = arc4random_uniform(3) ;   
    float x = ([valueOne.text floatValue]-1.5)/1.5;
    float c = (5+[valueTwo.text floatValue])/2;
    float o = (x+c)/2+f;

    total.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.fcm", o]; 

}
```

My Question: I'm searching the code/a guide showing me how to use a pickerview, by that I mean:
1. User enters ValueOne in textfield.
2. User Picks one of 4 Options which is ValueTwo (in the .m-> float c valueTwo.text should be filled in for one of the 4 variables which i want to set).
So how can i get the pickerview with pre-set variables and the user just has to pick it?

If anything is un-clear feel free to comment.

Edit: I want the keyboard to hide and pickerview to show instead and the pickerview should only show up when textfield valueTwo is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a combination of the two answers above.

First, Setup your class to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,
    UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
...
@end
```

Next, Declare properties for your array of items, and the picker view.
Then you can create your picker view in code (or in the Nib).  In either case, make sure you set the `delegate` and `datasource` properties of the picker to your view controller.

Set the `delegate` property of the text field that you want to modify to `self` and then implement this method:

```
- (void)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textfield {
  [self presentPicker];
  return NO;
}
```

*Hat tip to @DavidH*

You can define the picker method like this:

```
- (void)presentPicker {
  UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:SOME_FRAME_HERE];
  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.dataSource = self;

  // TODO: animate this on screen
  [self.view addSubview picker];
}
```

Finally, you have to implement the requisite methods in those protocols:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return self.items.count;  //where items is your array of items
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return [self.items objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Take a look at the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol's methods to see how you'd respond to user selection and dismiss the picker.

*As a shameless self-promotion, I recently posted an episode on [NSScreencast](http://nsscreencast.com) on [how to build a custom picker view component](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/25-building-a-custom-picker-component) that includes dimming out the view behind it, animating it on & off the screen, and adding a toolbar for Done & Cancel buttons.*  I only mention this here because it's directly relevant to what you're trying to do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple - you should have an ivar array that contains all the elements that you will be loading to the pickerview. Once you have new input from the user you update the array. The array will be loaded automatically when the user fires up the picker view through the method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component      
 {
return [array objectAtIndex:row];
 }
```

This one updates the number of rows based on the new array:

```
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

 return [array count];
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will use a UITextFieldDelegate call "textFieldShouldBeginEditing:" and return NO for the one that you want to use a picker with. When you get that message and are prepared to send NO, you will then animate your picker into view. When the user chooses a value you will set that value on the textField in question, and dismiss the picker.

Comment: Its not a few lines of code in one place. You need to learn how to use a UITextField delegate. You need to learn how to animate a picker into view, out of view, and how to use its delegate. These are the things you need to do if you want to develop iOS software. That's what everyone else does.